# How to search an excel range on cell's (border) colour in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010, office-interop

I've written a method in C# which loops through an excel range cell by cell, row by row and compare it's (border) colour against the colour I'm looking for. This works - of course - but it is pretty slow...

Is there a possibility I could use the Find method on my range? I googled this but I can't find anything related to finding something else than text.

Comment: Is this excel interop?

Comment: Can you post your slow version of the code?

Comment: I don't think that would be very relevant; I simply loop through the cells one by one and use an if-statement to compare the properties.

Comment: I've worked in VBA for some time and I don't recall any other option to do this. Hopefully I'm wrong.

Comment: Ok well I'm voting to close the question.  You want people to help fix your code, but can't be bothered to actually *post* the code.  You want to know why your code is slow, but won't even say what technology you're using to interact with Excel.  Best of luck!

Comment: Dear Mike Christensen, maybe you should read what I write instead of judging without thinking. I explain to you exactly what I do. I do not what to fix the code I have now, I want something else.

The question is how can I find on a background colour or a border colour using the Find method on a range; I think that would be much faster. What use do you have seeing the code I want to get rid off???

Comment: @Tyress; Yes this excel is interop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Denise I doubt you can use any Find methods on interop to check for cell style. If you're limiting the range already and going cell-by-cell on a foreach, my only advice is to use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). We were converted when we realized that the speed is increased more than tenfold for sheets with at least 30,000 rows, plus you can use LINQ and no messy interop stuff.

Using EPPlus you would only need to do something like:

```
//looking for cells with a yellow border on its left side
IEnumerable<ExcelRangeBase> matches = worksheet.Cells.Where(c => c.Style.Border.Left.Color.Rgb == "FFFFFF00");
```

Comment: Thanks I'm going to look into EPPlus!